# Flash based network graphing?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a flash widget that can read, say JSON/XML data, and create an interactive network graph that which users can drag nodes around? I'm not looking for software that creates static images... but something more dynamic, like "heavier" the node, the bigger it looks. That kind of Flash widget.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any widgets that do your specific task. You can use [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) , it is an ActionScript library for data visulaization. This will be able to provide you the necessary code to implement your needs.

Try looking at the [demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo) and select the Force Directed Layout ( I think this is closest to what you want ) To change node size you may have to read the tutorial and go through the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

1. [yFiles FLEX](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesflex_about.html) from the makers of the awesome [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html)
2. the "Drag Node" charts in [PowerCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/powercharts/gallery/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a simple as3 application using http://www.cove.org/ape/ for the physics part and the as3 package for json/xml parsing.